# DatabaseMetaData.getColumns returning an empty ResultSet for synonyms

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The method `getColumns()` on the metadata is returning an empty ResultSet for Synonyms (for tables and views it's returning the list of columns properly).

This happens on Oracle 11g Express and using the latest Oracle JDBC driver (11.2.3).

Does this happen for other SQL servers too?

Any help/ideas to solve this issue are welcome.

Comment: are you calling the resultsetmetadataobject.getColumns() with in resultset or outside?

Comment: openedConnection.getMetaData() and then metaData.getColumn(...)

Comment: It should not give empty resultset if schema available.Give your code here .What are you passing as getColumns() arguments

Comment: @icCube are you interested for getting coulmn names?

Comment: COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_SIZE, DECIMAL_DIGITS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the Oracle drivers does not return information on synonyms in `getColumns()`. This is documented in the Oracle 11g JDBC Developer's Guide under [Performance Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28785):

> Considerations for getColumns
>
> By default, the `getColumns` method does not retrieve information about the columns if a synonym is specified. To enable the retrieval of information if a synonym is specified, you must call the `setIncludeSynonyms` method on the connection as follows:
>
> ```
> ( (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)conn ).setIncludeSynonyms(true)
> ```
>
> This will cause all subsequent `getColumns` method calls on the connection to include synonyms. This is similar to `setRemarksReporting`. Alternatively, you can set the `includeSynonyms` connection property. This is similar to the `remarksReporting` connection property.
>
> However, bear in mind that if `includeSynonyms` is true, then the name of the object returned in the `table_name` column will be the synonym name, if a synonym exists. This is true even if you pass the table name to `getColumns`.

Note that this last item is really important to keep in mind!

Comment: Is this the case for Oracle 12c too? Can't seem to get this working!

Comment: @BPavanKumar To be honest, I don't know. I don't use Oracle that much.

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
PreparedStatement pt=coneection.preparestatement("select * from table_name");
Resultset rs=pt.executeQuery();
ResultsetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(coulmn_number));
System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnType(column_number));
```

**Another way**

```
PreparedStatement pt=coneection.preparestatement("select * from table_name");
    Resultset rs=pt.executeQuery();
    ResultsetMetaData rsmd=pt.getMetaData();
    System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(coulmn_number));
    System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnType(column_number));
```