# How to get dynamically in the Java Code about the function or procedure parameters of a synonym in an Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I had got the solution for getting columns of a synonym table when browsed stackoverview 
[DatabaseMetaData.getColumns returning an empty ResultSet for synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545646/databasemetadata-getcolumns-returning-an-empty-resultset-for-synonyms)

But could not get any reference for getting function params dynamically in Java Code for a function synonym in Database. Need suggestion

Comment: What kind of "function parameters" are you talking about?  A PL/SQL function? You can use [getFunctionColumns()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getFunctionColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) for that

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is PL/SQL function,...I have used it but not getting columns info for Synonym PL/SQL function...I have used like this.......................metaData.getFunctionColumns(connection.getCatalog(), "SchemaName", "functionname", null);

Comment: As mentioned in getColumns for synonym table used 
( (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)conn ).setIncludeSynonyms(true)......but not getting column names of a PL/SQL function call with getFunctionColumns()... Please advice

Comment: You need to pass the **real** function name to that JDBC method. Not a synonym name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...we will not get the real function name ... a function, say func1() in schema1 is created as synonym function as test_func() in schema2,,, we have to access to schema2 and get dynamically the synonyms and then for synonym functions (i.e. test_func()) we have to get the column parameters dynamically...looks possible?

Comment: If you can't get the real function name, you can't retrieve details about the function - simple as that.

Comment: Ok. .that means I have to connect to Schema1 where real function is there...as I cannot get the real function name from Schema2 as they are synonym names...in that case this doesn't work...Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

> ...a function, say func1() in schema1 is created as synonym function as
>   test_func() in schema2

You can use the data dictionary views to get the **real** function name, function owner and even procedure parameters.

Here you can get the information re the synonym - the owner, real function name:

```
select table_owner, table_name, table_owner||'.'||table_name full_function_name
from   all_synonyms
where  owner in ('PUBLIC',user)
and    synonym_name = 'FUNC1'
```

Having defined the owner of the function (schema2 name in your case) and the real function name - you can extract the parameters from db query:

```
select * 
from   all_arguments
where  owner = _table_owner_
and    object_name = _table_name_
```

Hope this helps.